# Float to 4 uint8_t and display

Tags: c++, floating-point, memcpy, std-bitset

I read from float in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) and i tried print his bits.
i used std::bitset and this return other bits different from what I expected(i know because i used the same number of the example in the link), then i used memcpy() and copy the memory of float to 4 parts of 1 byte each and print, this method worked but i have 4 questions.

1) Why using bitset in a float, this print only the integer part?
2) Why bitset working only with the array and not with the float?
3) memcpy() worked in correct order?

The last question is because  `0.15625f == 0b00111110001000000000000000000000`.
Then i think that the correct order is:

```
bb[0] == 0b00111110;
bb[1] == 0b00100000;
bb[2] == 0b00000000;
bb[3] == 0b00000000;
```

But the order returned is inverse.

4) Why happend this ?

***My code:***

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main(int argc,char** argv){

        float f = 0.15625f;

        std::cout << std::bitset<32>(f) << std::endl;
        //print: 00000000000000000000000000000000
        //This print only integer part of the float. I tried with 5.2341 and others

        uint8_t bb[4];
        memcpy(bb, &f, 4);

        std::cout << std::bitset<8>(bb[0]) << std::endl;
        //print: 00000000
        std::cout << std::bitset<8>(bb[1]) << std::endl;
        //print: 00000000
        std::cout << std::bitset<8>(bb[2]) << std::endl;
        //print: 00100000
        std::cout << std::bitset<8>(bb[3]) << std::endl;
        //print: 00111110

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Endianness? Looks like you're running on a little endian computer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: `std::bitset<32>(f)` will first convert `f` into `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Constructor std::bitset<N>( unsigned long val ). You can use ` uint32_t f2 = *((uint32_t*)(&f));
       std::cout << std::bitset<32>(f2) << std::endl;`

Comment: @shang12, `((uint32_t)(&f))` is undefined behavior. Use `memcpy`.

Comment: Character asterisk(*) doesn't  display in my comment. I want to write uint32_t f2 = * ((uint32_t  *  )(&f))

Comment: @shang12, `*` is not the problem. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

Comment: @Evg, thank for your information. With built-in data type, this is not the problem.

Comment: @shang12, if you want your code to conform to the C++ standard, it **is** a problem. If you don't, do it.

Comment: @shang12 Wrap any code in the comments (and any inline code in questions/answers) in \` symbols. So \`asd\` will turn into `asd`. And listen to Evg, the correct way to do it is `memcpy`. Compilers understand what you are doing and will optimize it away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To construct `std::bitset` from a `float`, one of `std::bitset` [construtors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset) is used. The one that is relevant here is

   ```
   constexpr bitset(unsigned long long val) noexcept;
   ```

   Before this constructor is called, `float` is converted into `unsigned long long`, and its decimal part is truncated. `std::bitset` has no constructors that take floating-point values.
2. The bytes order of floating-point numbers is [affected by machine endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Floating-point_and_endianness). On a little-endian machine bytes are stored in the reverse order. If your machine uses the same endianness for floating-point numbers and for integers, you can simply write

   ```
   float f = 0.15625f;
   std::uint32_t b;
   std::memcpy(&b, &f, 4);
   std::cout << std::bitset<32>(b) << std::endl; 
   // Output: 00111110001000000000000000000000
   ```

   to get bytes in the correct order automatically.